# How can I compare current server time with SQL Database timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to compare current time with predefined timestamp range (start_time and end_time) from database. But the query returns nothing. Will be grateful for any kind of help.

```
    public function setCurrentGw()  //Isn't allowed to set externally
    {
        $this->table='gameweek';
        $current_time = new time();

        $query="SELECT `gw`,`start_time`,`end_time` FROM `$this->table` WHERE `start_time`<=$current_time AND $current_time<=`end_time`";

        if($q=mysql_query($query))
        {
            $temp=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
            $this->current_gw=$temp['gw'];
            echo $temp['start_time'];
            echo 'Current#'.$this->current_gw.'<br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Technical Failure! Try Again';
        }
    }
```

Comment: use NOW();to get current time in mysql

Comment: The `mysql_...` functions should not be used anymore as they will be removed in future versions of PHP. Please use PDO or the `mysqli_...` functions, [see docs](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing)

Comment: Please show the table structure, or at least explain what the data types are for `start_time` and `end_time`.

Comment: datatypes for start_time and end_time is timestamp @GordonLinoff

Comment: Does using `now()` fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OP declared that `NOW()` worked.